# How to integrate paytm with mobile app using php

Tags: php, android, ios, paytm

I am trying to integrate Paytm with andorid and ios app using php,
I found code on github and two files "generateChecksum.php" and "verifyChecksum.php" (added my merchant id in "config_paytm" file)
and i generated checksum id succesfully,now what is the next step ? How can i integrate paytm with app using php ?

here is code for generateChecksum.php

```
$findme   = 'REFUND';
$findmepipe = '|';

$paramList = array();

$paramList["MID"] = '1';
$paramList["ORDER_ID"] = '11';
$paramList["CUST_ID"] = '1';
$paramList["INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"] = '1';
$paramList["CHANNEL_ID"] = '1';
$paramList["TXN_AMOUNT"] = '1';
$paramList["WEBSITE"] = '';

foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{  
  $pos = strpos($value, $findme);
  $pospipe = strpos($value, $findmepipe);
  if ($pos === false || $pospipe === false) 
    {
        $paramList[$key] = $value;
    }
}



//Here checksum string will return by getChecksumFromArray() function.
$checkSum = getChecksumFromArray($paramList,PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY);
//print_r($_POST);
 echo json_encode(array("CHECKSUMHASH" => $checkSum,"ORDER_ID" => $_POST["ORDER_ID"], "payt_STATUS" => "1"),JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Comment: Is your PHP integrated to pHP correctly?

Comment: @bhuvneshpattnaik: Yes

Comment: Here is the perfect example of paytm integration in android app refer this ... https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/paytm-integration-android-example/

Comment: You can use just use `Retrofit library` in your android app to connect to PHP which is already integrated to Paytm.

For IOS, you can simply use `cocoapods`

Comment: @TakeInfos: And what about IOS ?

Comment: #bhuvnesh pattnaik: Thank you for your reply but what is steps for do this ? what is use of php in this ?

Comment: PHP will act as your backEnd code, where you can store details of each user in the app. Despite of this Follow the following link
For android : https://developer.paytm.com/docs/v1/android-sdk/   
For IOS : https://developer.paytm.com/docs/v1/ios-sdk/